# What is the difference between to learn and to study?

Tags: word-choice

If I'm doing homework, actually I'm **learning** or **studying**? 
If I'm at the university, actually I'm learning or studying?

I'm confused of that, and always I don't know what is the right word to choose. Is it a matter of personal choosing and everyone can choose what he wants of these two?

Comment: **[Is there any subtle difference between “to study” and “to learn”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19533/is-there-any-subtle-difference-between-to-study-and-to-learn)**

Comment: *Studying* is an **activity** which may or may not result in the **accomplishment** *learning*. See our tag wiki on [aspect](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

Comment: To add to the answer and comments, both *learn* and *study* have more than one meaning; and *study* can also be a noun, as well as a verb. In the meaning you mention, we "study" to "learn" about a subject. And we "learn" to gain knowledge and/or skill. The word "study" usually implies an education context (a school, a university, etc.), and in this context we usually "learn" a subject by "studying" it. The two words, though different, are closely related in the education context.

Comment: Related: [Choosing the word: learn or study](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/118364/)

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to me if someone says 
"I **study** Physics in XYZ University." than 
"I **learn** Physics in XYZ University."

Look at one more example.  
"I have **learnt** how to calculate 1+1 today in school." 
"I have **studied** how to calculate 1+1 today in school."
The first one seems to tell people one has successfully obtained a certain skill, which the second does not tell.

I would say "**learn**" refers to gaining a certain new skill in mind while "**study**" refers to a relatively longer process for understanding something. If I were to prepare a coming examination in my room, I would choose "study" because I assume I have learnt everything I need in that semester.

Answer (score 1):

**Studying** is the action that causes to **learning**. In other words, after you study you get the learning. As you can see in the following citation:

> "As you **study**, you are making cell connections like these that
>   solidify memories and permit **learning** to occur." ([Cambell Biology, 10th Edition](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Reece-Campbell-Biology-10th-Edition/9780321775658.html), p.93)