# Choosing the word: learn or study

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There is a picture of a boy who is in class. In the picture the teacher is dictating a text, and the boy is writing it down.

The children are asked to describe this picture in one sentence: (What's he doing?) - He is...

Which verb is correct here, *learn* or *study*? Or both are correct? (The children don't know the difference between these two words yet, but they know that "to learn" means 'to get knowledge or skill' and "school" is a place where they gain more knowledge.)

> To learn – to gain knowledge or skill by studying, practicing, being
>   taught, or experiencing something.
>
> To study – to read, memorize facts, attend school, etc., in order to
>   learn about a subject. [Source](https://blog.abaenglish.com/what-is-the-difference-between-learn-and-study/)

Answer (score 3):

A student who is writing down what the teacher is saying, or who is taking notes about the teacher's lecture, is not **studying**.  **Studying** is the careful and attentive reading of written material about a particular subject, or the close examination of an object. The boy is **learning**, which is the acquisition of knowledge.

Comment: TRomano, you got my idea :) Learning or studying at school (yes, I know the difference)?

Comment: We aren't **studying** when we listen to a lecture and are taking notes. We are **learning**.

Comment: +1 but I think there is more flexibility than your answer suggests, people/native speakers and non, will use both terms. However, when a teacher is dictating a passage, students are practising several skills at the same time, they aren't reading, *and* taking down notes, which studying implies.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe the flexibility is not there. Native speakers will not say the student writing down notes or dictation is studying. Students may be said to be "studying at university" but that is not the verb phrase here.  Without "at university" or a similar locative, the bare -ing form of the verb means to be reading a text about a subject, carefully, or to be examining an object carefully.

Comment: **Studying** does not imply "reading and taking down notes". Students may take down notes while studying, but the note-taking is not integral to the act of studying.

Comment: He may or may not be learning. I know several students who are capable of writing down everything the teacher says, without learning a thing. He is studying, in that he is being a student. Sorry, but I think this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @James K The children are preschoolers, and it's important to give them an idea that school is a place where they gain knowledge, not just attend classes. I think there is a pedagogical nuance, too.

Comment: @James K: You should have studied harder.  "Studying" (all by its lonesome)  <> "being a student".  One can be "*studying to be* an engineer" but we need **to be** there to get the meaning "is a student (in a certain discipline)" or at the very least a direct object: "is studying *engineering*"

Comment: @Yulia I've yet to see a preschooler who sits passively taking dictation from a teacher! I don't think that is a good image of "learning" at all. Preschoolers may not even recognise this a classroom scene, as they don't yet attend school.

Comment: I don't concur. "Studying" is not always a solo activity. "studying" can mean "take a course". (dictionary.com sense 19). Hence studying is implied by the picture, whereas learning is not.

Comment: @ James K They are five-year-old children and they know something about going to school since they are being prepared for it and they see older students who study at the same school. In fact, they know a lot (I was surprised while talking with a boy from that preschool class - he knows a lot about school life).

Comment: Interesting discussion. I noticed that people don't often tell the difference when saying "learning/studying at school/at home".

Comment: @James K: Please supply a sentence where *intransitive and uncomplemented* **studying** means "take a course".

Answer (score 3):

> There is a picture of a boy who is in class. In the picture the teacher is dictating a text, and the boy is writing it down.

'Studying', when used to describe an *action or activity* of an individual (i.e. not in the meaning of 'the *state* of being a student'),  usually puts a focus on things they do *on their own*. As the teacher is prominent here, 'studying' is not a good choice.

'Learning' implies that the boy's knowledge or skill are actually increasing. This is possible, but not necessarily true based on the description of the picture.

So, while **neither 'learning' nor 'studying' are *good* answers**, 'learning' is the better *choice*, because it *may* be true.

As per userr2684291's comment, 'writing' is *technically* better than both if answers beyond 'learning' or 'studying' are allowed in the question, although it might be seen as a facetious answer.

Answer (score 1):

The dictation is a part of educational course, so it would be 'studying'.  Not 'learning', because nobody knows if that test or exercise really made the boy learn something.

I rather like *He is doing his dictation. *

Comment: perhaps "taking notes" or "taking dictation". On the other hand, he could be "doodling"

Comment: Yeah, That is the point.  Hah (High Five

Answer (score 0):

Learning refers to anything like learning to ride or sing or cook, but in terms of study it all related to something printed on paper.