# You can't "learn at school". Or you can?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This post continues [the previous one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118364/choosing-the-word-learn-or-study) I placed here yesterday.

The idiom "to study at school" means 'to attend school/to go to school/to be a student'. One cannot *learn* at school (there is no object in this sentence).

At the same time, we say "studying/learning at school/at home" and don't often tell the difference between these expressions.

I wonder if the verb "study" can be replaced with the "learn" in the idiom "to study at school" in the sense 'to be a student'.

Why is the "learn" used in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4031794/)? Is it possible to say "How to study effectively in medical school" (effective study grows into learning)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong or unidiomatic about "learn at school".  You are learning, and school is the place you are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> learn at school

is correct and understandable an object is not necessary

The pattern you are using is

> *verb* (*preposition*) *a location*
>
> camp in the woods
>   drive in the country
>   walk in the park

all are correct.

Comment: Are the expressions "to study at school" and "to learn at school" interchangeable?

Comment: @Yulia They are basically interchangeable as most people would understand the two phrases, those being pedantic might point out "studying" does not necessarily mean "learning".

Comment: It's actually very easy to study very hard and yet learn nothing.  My students do it all the time!  They study for the test, and then forget everything the next day.